# Using Altair to plot from one dataframe referencing multiple CSV url data sources

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit, altair

For a dataset containing spectra as individual csv files, I am making a viewer as a streamlit app, using altair (+ potentially VegaFusion if it makes sense) for plotting.

I have pandas dataframe where each row holds all properties of one spectrum (i.e. metadata) plus the unique filename of its csv-file. The csv files them selves are stored in an online repository, so they can be read by their url instead of local files.

```
> df.sample(3)

        Region      Campaign    Material_ID     file        x_unit      y_unit

8336        V       Spring              7       712d.csv    nm          Intensity
2452        V       Summer              3       56fd.csv    cm-1        Abs
730         L       Spring              3       0f28.csv    nm          Intensity

## ...this is just for illustration, the real df has many more columns...

> df.shape

(15809, 24)
```

The csv files them selves are simple 2-column x-y-data (several thousand rows each).

```
> 712d.csv  # one examplary csv file

0       nm,         Intensity
1       528.65,     1841.47
2       528.734,    1841.4
3       528.819,    1841.7
        ...
1599    660.917,    3328.73
1600    660.998,    3328.3
1601    661.079,    3324.4
```

Is there a better way to plot line graphs of a subset of the (interactively selected) spectra, than to inflate the df with x and y data by repeating the metadata as many times as there are data points in each spectrum? With just a few spectra selected for plotting this creates a df of tens of thousands of rows of mostly repetitive data.

One idea is, to read the spectral data into a single column of 2d arrays, but I can't think of a good way, how altair could read and plot it then.
Or maybe another library would be more appropriate here, like holoviz. But I am not experienced with this one.